# How do I cut just the file name from from ls -l output?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed, awk

I am in the process of [concatenating ogg audio files in bulk with the help of ffmpeg using a **mylist.txt** file](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

The format of the **mylist.txt** file is

```
file '/path/to/file1.wav'
file '/path/to/file2.wav'
file '/path/to/file3.wav'
```

My **'ls -l'** output sample of WhattsAPP ogg audio files is similar to

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work  64112 Nov 14 18:43 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-11 at 10.19.18 AM.ogg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work  24616 Nov 14 18:43 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-11 at 10.19.50 AM.ogg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work  26166 Nov 14 18:43 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-11 at 10.20.18 AM.ogg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work  69895 Nov 14 18:43 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-11 at 10.21.05 AM.ogg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work  85416 Nov 14 18:43 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-11 at 10.27.09 AM.ogg'
```

1. How do I get only the **'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-11 at 10.19.18 AM.ogg'** portions of each line in the **'ls -l'** output using **cut, sed, awk** or any other tool into a file using a single command?
2. How do I add the keyword **"file"** before all file names in the file using a single command?
3. Can process 1. & 2. be combined into a single command?

The contents of the final file need to look like:

```
file 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-12 at 10.21.59 AM.ogg'
file 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-12 at 10.29.45 AM.ogg'
file 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-12 at 10.31.52 AM.ogg'
file 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-12 at 9.31.38 AM.ogg'
```

Comment: You might want to read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider :-) will ask in super user now on.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman :-) what would be a better solution?

Comment: The accepted solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler to use a `glob` instead of `ls` to work with a list of file names

```
for f in *; do
  echo file \'$f\'
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bert :-) How do I add the single quotes for the file name in the output? Like **file 'WhatsApp Ptt 2019-11-12 at 10.21.59 AM.ogg'**

Comment: @SijuGeorge You can escape the single quotes using the backlash character, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you :-) it works!

Answer (score 3):

/bin/ls -1

That leaves out all the goo :)

The problem being that ls in most distributions is aliased to something like “ls -la”. You can check that with “alias ls” and see if anything comes up

Also using an absolute path (with /bin/) will avoid using the alias.

Comment: Thank you so much @FranzBettaag :-) How do I add the word *"file"* before the file name in every line?

Comment: /bin/ls -1 /your/directory | sed -e “s;^;file ;g”

Comment: And make sure to use normal double quotes, not the artistic ones my iphone makes :)

Comment: Thank you :-) I am on Ubuntu and it gave the error "^: command not found". But I got the solution from @Bert. Thanks again for caring to help :-)